# Jenkins pipeline script to write value of variable in file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am extracting the username/password from credential store and I am assigning it to a variable. I want to write this value in a file.
I am using the below code:

```
for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) {
            if(creds.id == "credential"){
            def password = creds.password
            println(creds.username)
            println(password)
            writeFile file: '\\Jenkins_Home\\workspace\\test\\test.properties', text: 'pass=${password}'
```

It prints the value of password.
But it just writes pass=${password}, not the value of the password.

How can I write the values of the variable in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the double quotes as mentioned by Sriram. He is correct that pipeline groovy script does have issue with single quotes.

Also found sometimes that double quotes can also be an issue and that they have to be escaped (\"). See how you go!

I also have another solution, where you can define the text going into the file as a variable and enclosing the writeFile arguments in brackets, see below:

```
in jenkinsCredentials) {
        if(creds.id == "credential"){
        def password = creds.password
        println(creds.username)
        println(password)
        def pass = "pass=" + password
        writeFile (file: '\\Jenkins_Home\\workspace\\test\\test.properties', text: pass)
```

Comment: I want to extract another password and append that password with the test.properties file . How can that be achieved.

Comment: Groovy does not have issue with single quotes. It's just that single quotes do not support interpolation. See documentation here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation (or in Groovy docs).

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') as below:

```
writeFile file: "\\Jenkins_Home\\workspace\\test\\test.properties", text: "pass=${password}"
```

For some reason, pipeline groovy script has some issue with single quotes(')

Comment: I want to extract another password and append that password with the test.properties file . How can that be achieved

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you want to update the password in the same loop as above?